# jQuery append div inside div with id and manipulate

Tags: jquery, html

after 2 hours of searching I decided to ask my question.

I have a div:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

I want to add a div inside the above div using jQuery.

I tried (following code is inside a function):

```
var e = $('<div style="display:block; float:left;width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px; margin-top:'+positionY+'px;margin-left:'+positionX+'px;border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;"></div>');
$('div', e).attr('id', 'myid');
$("#box").append(e);
```

But accessing `$("#myid")` is not working.

Any idea on how to add a div inside a div and be able to manipulate them?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's just the wrong order

```
var e = $('<div style="display:block; float:left;width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px; margin-top:'+positionY+'px;margin-left:'+positionX+'px;border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;"></div>');
$('#box').append(e);    
e.attr('id', 'myid');
```

Append first and then access/set attr.

Comment: Why use three lines of code, when only one is needed?  Why attach the id afterwards when it can just be put right into the source HTML?

Comment: I'm just trying to solve the original problem, not to improve it.

Comment: I was hoping the OP would see that there was an improved way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

You're overcomplicating things:

```
var e = $('<div style="display:block; float:left;width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px; margin-top:'+positionY+'px;margin-left:'+positionX+'px;border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;"></div>');
e.attr('id', 'myid');
$('#box').append(e);
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Dm5J2/

Answer (score 3):

Why not go even simpler with either one of these options:

```
$("#box").html('<div id="myid" style="display:block; float:left;width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px; margin-top:'+positionY+'px;margin-left:'+positionX+'px;border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;"></div>');
```

Or, if you want to append it to existing content:

```
$("#box").append('<div id="myid" style="display:block; float:left;width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px; margin-top:'+positionY+'px;margin-left:'+positionX+'px;border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;"></div>');
```

Note: I put the `id="myid"` right into the HTML string rather than using separate code to set it.

Both the `.html()` and `.append()` jQuery methods can take a string of HTML so there's no need to use a separate step for creating the objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = $('<div style="display:block; id="myid" float:left;width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px; margin-top:'+positionY+'px;margin-left:'+positionX+'px;border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;"></div>');
$("#box").html(e);
```

Comment: The `.html()` method takes a string, not a jQuery object as it's argument.