# Setting the height of the body to be more than the height of an absolute div

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute div as the main content area on my page design. I have another div that occupies the top portion and which is 450px in height. I cannot know the height of absolute div before page load, so will only be able to find it out after page load has happened.

Now the problem is that my body also occupies 450px (height), so if I want to display something after the absolute div has ended I am unable to do so.

Summary :

```
Absolute Div : 600px (for example, don't know the actual height) Has position:absolute.
Top Div : 450px (No position:absolute)
Body Becomes 450 px as expected
```

**How do I place a div below the absolute div. Currently the only thing I can think of is jQuery.**

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zr3Zw/3/) I made to the illustrate the problem. Even though the whole body displays blue, if you fire up the developer tool and inspect, you'll see that the html and body both occupy

[image: Body Height is less]

UPDATE : [Linky](http://bit.ly/XyUSOp) I'm trying to display the main content area above a few elements. Those circles that you see are seperate elements. And they need to stay that way.

Comment: Absolute positioning removes absolute div from the flow and the body wont know it's there. I'm sure you can do what you are trying to do without absolute positioning. Why have you decided it needs to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14863356/Blah/index.html I'm trying to dispaly the main content area above a few elements. Those circles that you see are seperate elements. And they need to stay that way.

Comment: It's all bit complicated for me to understand in its current state. Do you think you could make a simplified version including the circles?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn more about the positions!
Anyhow the current problem you are referring to will be solve if you change the position to relative!

```
<div id="First Div" style="height:100px;width:50px;position:relative;background-color:green;">
</div>
<div id="BelowDiv" style="height:100px;width:50px;position:relative;background-color:pink;">
</div>
```

But if you really need to place it somewhere static or in another word "absolute", then you need to place a container div and set the position to absolute, then place the other two or even more  or  inside the container Div.

```
<div id="container" style="position:absolute; top:y; left:x">
     <div id="FirstDiv" style="position:relative;></div>
     <div id="SecondDiv" style="position:relative;></div>
</div>
```

You can use jquery to append tags to your container. [here is the sample link to do it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911916/jquery-append-div-inside-div-with-id-and-manipulate)

If it didn't help try the `height:auto` and also `overflow:visible` for your container!